# When do browsers refresh a stale cache entry?

Tags: http, caching

I've been trying to refresh my understanding of HTTP/1.1 caching - something I find I have to do every once in a while, as there seems to be too many possible combinations for my brain to remember reliably.

I took it as a given that the `Expires` or `max-age` cache control directives were used by browsers as hints, not ironclad laws: if a cache entry is stale (older than its max age), the browser MAY validate it.

A colleague and I had a bit of a row about this and he forced me to read the RFC, which I felt was a bit harsh but proved him entirely right: if I understand it correctly, clients are not allowed to use a cache entry that they know to be stale.

In other words: if a document specifies a `max-age` cache header, and no other directives such as `must-validate` affect caching behaviour, and that document's cache entry becomes stale, the browser will always re-validate it.

This is entirely clear and logical, and to put that argument to rest, I set out to confirm it empirically by having a server serve a test JavaScript file with the following headers:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2014 22:11:28 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Server: testServer/1.0
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

This JavaScript file is included by an HTML page hosted on the same server through a `<script>` element in the document's `<head>`. The HTML page is served with the following cache control header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, max-age=0
```

After loading the HTML page, I clicked through to a different page, waited 5 minutes for good measure and clicked on a link back to the original page, monitoring all HTTP requests - and the test file was never requested. This was reproduced consistently with both Firefox and Safari at their latest versions.

This got a bit long-winded, but the gist of my question is: my tests seem to show that mainstream browsers do not respect the RFC and will not revalidate stale cache entries. Did I misinterpret the RFC? Just as likely, did I botch my tests, and can someone prove them wrong? Or do browsers really not respect the `max-age` cache directive?

Comment: `HTTP/1.0` or `HTTP/1.1`? I'm with you BTW, I don't assume browsers will obey a MUST in RFC's when it comes to cache anyway...

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've edited the question to specify `HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: How do you let the browser request this file, do you use it as source for a script tag in an html document? With what caching headers is that document served? What do you mean with "navigate away and come back", (how) do you refresh the containing page?

Comment: I've updated the question: the script is included through a `<script>` tag, I do not refresh the containing page but load it from an external link, "navigating away" means going on another page (in order to be able to go back to the original one without forcibly refreshing it), the HTML page is served with `Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, max-age=0`

Comment: That would mean the containing page would be re-requested when you hit Back. Can you see that happening (is "the test file" you refer to the html or js file)? Is the JavaScript actually used on the page?

Comment: The containing page is indeed re-requested, which was rather the point - although I don't hit back but an explicit link to the page. The JavaScript file is indeed being used, but is not re-requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. I have tried to, using ASP.NET MVC, with the following code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", 
                       "no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store, max-age=0");
    return View();
}

public ActionResult JavaScript()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=30");
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Page2()
{
    return View();
}
```

The first action returns the Index page (relevant headers only):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 182


<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/Home/JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/Home/Page2">Page 2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript is returned like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 24


document.write('Foo');
```

And Page2 merely contains a link back to Home.

Now when I, using Internet Explorer 11, Chrome 32 or Firefox 26, I see the following behavior:

- Upon the first request to `/`, the Index document is requested as well as the JavaScript file, and they are returned like shown above as verified with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com).
- When I click the "Page 2" link, only Page 2 is requested, because it doesn't contain anything but a link back to Page 1.
- Now when I click the "Home" link from Page 2 within 30 seconds, the JS file is **not** requested again in any browser.
- When I wait a while (> 30 seconds) on Page 2 and then click the "Home" link, the JS file **is** requested in all three browsers.

However, when I **click the Back button** from Page 2 in any browser after any period of time (either greater or less than 30 seconds), the Index file is always, but the JS file is **never** requested again in any browser.

It requires a refresh (F5) or navigating away and back by clicking "Page 2" followed by "Home" again to make the browser perform a new request for the JS file after it became stale.

Comment: Your first finding (the JS being re-loaded after 30s when being linked to `/`) doesn't match my own, but I'm inclined to trust your results more than mine: they conform to what the RFC says should happen. On the other hand, the fact that it's not being reloaded when going back in the history seems like a clear violation of the RFC to me. You don't appear to agree, and I'd be interested in your reasons.

Comment: @Nicolas I'm just reporting what I see. :-) It's weird that your browsers seem to show different behavior for the same headers. I would expect a back-click to initiate a reload of the JS file too, as the browser knows it's stale, and it does seem to do so for the index document. More experimenting (or reading the browser's issue tracker, mailing list or source code) will be required to find out why this is happening, I guess. Feel free not to accept this answer until someone more knowledgeable comes around.

Comment: After triple checking my tests, your results are the correct ones: going back to the root page through a link *will* cause stale entries to be revalidated, going back to it through the browser's history won't. After some more digging, I found that section [13.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.13) of the RFC explained why this is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

After much digging and help from @CodeCaster, the canonical answer to this question is that browsers do appear to respect the RFC: stale cache entries are always re-validated, except in the very specific case that they were accessed, directly or indirectly, through the browser's history. In this case, section [13.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.13) of the RFC applies:

> History mechanisms and caches are different. In particular history mechanisms SHOULD NOT try to show a semantically transparent view of the current state of a resource. Rather, a history mechanism is meant to show exactly what the user saw at the time when the resource was retrieved.